# How to generate bitcode from dragonegg

Tags: gcc, llvm

Back when *dragonegg* was in *llvm-gcc* one could issue `-emit-llvm` and it did generate llvm bitcode. Now when I use dragonegg as a plugin (`gcc -fplugin=dragonegg.so`) I cannot find any such option anymore. The only thing I found was generating LLVM IR - which is not what I want.
How is it still possible to generate bitcode?

GCC is 4.6, LLVM and Dragonegg are current SVN. And using clang is not an option since its C++11 support is feeble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since outputting LLVM bitcode doesn't seem to be possible anymore I wrote a python script which then feeds the IR to *llvm-as* which then gives me bitcode. Performance-wise this is a catastrophe, but at least it works.

```
#/usr/bin/env python

import sys, subprocess

args = list(sys.argv)
del args[0] # Remove our exec name
compiler = args[0] 
del args[0] # Remove the compile name

compileArguments = [compiler]
outputFile = ''

foundFile = False

for arg in args:
if arg.startswith('-o'):
    foundFile = True
elif foundFile:
    outputFile = arg
    foundFile = False
    arg = "/dev/stdout"

compileArguments.append(arg)

compileProcess = subprocess.Popen(compileArguments, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
asbin = 'llvm-as'

ir2bcProcess = subprocess.Popen([asbin, '-f', '-o=' + outputFile], stdin=compileProcess.stdout)

stdout, stderr = ir2bcProcess.communicate()

compileProcess.wait()
ir2bcProcess.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [README](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/dragonegg/trunk/README):

> ```
> -fplugin-arg-dragonegg-emit-ir
> -flto
>   Output LLVM IR rather than target assembler.  You need to use -S with this,
>   since otherwise GCC will pass the output to the system assembler (these don't
>   usually understand LLVM IR).  It would be nice to fix this and have the option
>   work with -c too but it's not clear how.  If you plan to read the IR then you
>   probably want to use the -fverbose-asm flag as well (see below).
> ```

Comment: From the [Docs](http://llvm.org/docs/BitCodeFormat.html): What is commonly known as the LLVM bitcode file format (also, sometimes anachronistically known as bytecode) is actually two things: a bitstream container format and an encoding of LLVM IR into the container format.

Comment: While one can get the IR you need also the container. Besides I already tried LLVM IR and it is not begin recognized by other LLVM tools.